# Increase the size of the modal window, if the user clicked on the choice of color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Increase the size of the modal window, if the user clicked on the choice of color.

[An example of how it happens in the moment.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QKG88.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in select's change event.Ex:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('.modal-content').css('width', '900px');
});
```